# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Producer

Tags: java, gradle, apache-kafka

I'm trying to use Kafka:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

public class SimpleProducer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
    }
}
```

But getting the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Producer

build.gradle:

```
...

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '2.2.0'
}

...
```

Comment: How are you running your `SimpleProducer`?

Comment: The Producer class is in fact within the kafka-clients-2.2.0.jar file. It seems like the jar is not on your classpath, when you run the class.

Comment: @Harald using command line

Comment: @user152468 how do I put it on my classpath?

Comment: It seems you are missing the import for org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer and java.util.Properties. Also you need to run this using gradle which will include the jar files on the classpath. I suggest looking up how to use the 'application' plugin for gradle for your version of gradle ('gradle -version')

Comment: @Zergleb sorry I omitted most of the code here in the question in the sake of clarity, but I actually have all the imports. The actual code is the SimpleProduce application from here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_simple_producer_example.htm

Comment: @Zergleb I want to run it from command line as they do in this tutorial.

Comment: @Alon in that tutorial they avoid the NoClassDefFoundError by adding <path/to/kafka> to the class path using the -cp argument as mentioned in the tutorial. I was able to avoid the NoClassDefFoundError on my local machine by instead adding the application plugin to gradle and adding a mainClass argument (in this case <whateveryounamedthepackage.SimpleProducer>) and then I ran 'gradle run' from the command line. This would have gradle handle the classpath arguments for you instead. But basically your java command needs to know where to find the jar files that have the classes it's looking for.

Comment: @Zergleb I just tried it. I managed to compile using javac as they do, and it created a SimpleProducer.class file, but when I try to execute it it throws: Error: Could not find or load main class SimpleProducer

Comment: Hi @Alon, I get the same error man. Error: Could not find or load main class SimpleProducer, no idea why though, worked perfectly till compilation. Also in your answer, you have this "TestProejct-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar", would you still know what's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran:

```
java -jar TestProejct-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -cp "D:\Software\kafka_2.12-2.2.0\libs\kafka-clients-2.2.0.jar"
```

There were several problems:

1. java doesn't aceept both -jar and -cp, so I had to include my jar in the classpath itself in addition to Kafka.
2. I had to specify the main class I wanted to run.
3. There was more than one jar to import from Kafka, so I had to specify * insead of kafka-clients-2.2.0.jar.

This solved the problem:

```
java -cp "D:\Software\kafka_2.12-2.2.0\libs\*;TestProejct-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" SimpleProducer
```

Comment: Hi @Alon, I get the same error man. Error: Could not find or load main class SimpleProducer, no idea why though, worked perfectly till compilation. Also in your answer, you have this "TestProejct-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar", would you still know what's that?

Answer (score 0):

I had tried with the following dependency in gradle.

```
compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '2.1.0'
```

Also, I provide below the code snippet for which I tested.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;

public class Producer {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.119.139:9092");
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        KafkaProducer kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer(properties);
        TestCallback callback = new TestCallback();
        try{
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                System.out.println("----->"+i);
                kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord("test", Integer.toString(i), "test message - " + i ));
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            kafkaProducer.close();
        }
    }


    private static class TestCallback implements Callback {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
            if (e != null) {
                System.out.println("Error while producing message to topic :" + recordMetadata);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } else {
                String message = String.format("sent message to topic:%s partition:%s  offset:%s", recordMetadata.topic(), recordMetadata.partition(), recordMetadata.offset());
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested this code using Eclipse IDE. Also remember, apache kafka client also downloads the following dependencies.

- zstd-jni-1.3.5-4.jar
- lz4-java-1.5.0.jar
- snappy-java-1.1.7.2.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar

If you want to run using command you have to run by specifying the -classpath with a set of jar files. I provide an example below.

```
java.exe -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath somelocation/a.jar;somelocation/b.jar;somelocation/c.jar
```

If it still does not solve your problem, provide the application structure, post code details so that others can help you.

Comment: Configure your project using any ide like eclipse or intellij idea and then run it.

Comment: I use InteliJ to develop/configure it, but run the project through command line. It doesn't work.

Comment: While running in command line use -cp option for classpath setting. Check and learn what java -cp option.

Comment: Are you able to compile ? Can you post the complete error details ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Producer
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more

Comment: Yes build successfull